# How to upload video into wowza while i shoot from iphone and link it to parse using swift?

Tags: swift, wowza

I am pretty new to wowza and for my app, I am using Parse as a backend. i have worked out a way to upload a video to parse after it is shot but now i need to upload it so it is LIVE. I heard that wowza is a good option to do that. So how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Convert AV to a format Wowza works with**

If you can convert the uploaded format into something wowza can ingest (rtmp or rtsp, ffmpeg might be handy) you can transcode it into HLS format.

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i <input> -strict -2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 <rtsp route>
```

where input is source video, and rtsp route is of the form rtsp:/someIP/app-6093/d8d26f76 and references your transcode/wowza IP